# Is R 4.0.x backward compatible with R 3.6.x?

Tags: r, backwards-compatibility

I have inherited a project developed and debugged in R 3.6.1. Should I expect it to work on R 4.0.x (currently most recent version is 4.0.3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

R almost always is, without exception.

One recent minor issue (affecting 3.6.0 relative to earlier verions) was related to a bub fix to the uniform random number generator making previously generated sequences (used also for sampling) different from current ones, but even that was very well signalled. See the files [NEWS.Rd](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd), [NEWS.3.Rd](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.3.Rd), [NEWS.2.Rd](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.2.Rd), [NEWS.1](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.1) and [NEWS.0](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.0) for the very careful, very explicit lists of changes.

Best of all you don't even have to trust my word. You could install R 4.0.* as a Docker container and try your code and convince yourself.

*Edit:*  I happen to maintain R for Debian and also Docker, so I have several version of the container here.  Witness how the following code to draw three N(0,1) numbers gets the *same result for four different years of R*.  Had I more containers or older R here I could show more.

```
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.3.1 Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); rnorm(3)'
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.4.4 Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); rnorm(3)'
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.5.3 Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); rnorm(3)'
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.6.3 Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); rnorm(3)'
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.0.3 Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); rnorm(3)'
[1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284
edd@rob:~$
```

Comment: the big change that could bite could be stringsAsFactors in read.table et al

Comment: Just a quick question. Is it possible to generate the exact same numbers in c++ and in R using the Mersenne Twister RGN and the same seed?

Comment: Yes! Even caveat I mentioned affected only the uniform generator. See the example I am posting now.