Does the "R" Language have a supported version list similar to Python?
I've been peeling through the documentation, but can't seem to find anything similar to what Python supports similar to this. I know it's a smaller community and may not have the same level of support and maintenance as Python, but I was wondering if there was anything similar. Thanks in advance.
Looked through the source documentation here and asked online but could not find any good references.

The current version of R is the supported version. In the link, as of today, that's version R 4.4.0.

If you don't get an answer here you could ask on r-help@r-project.org or r-devel@r-project.org.  Basically, only the latest release is fully supported, although (1) packages are still tested on the previously released version and (2) there may be the possibility of backports to address a recently discovered vulnerability

So R does not support any version besides the most recent? Are users expected to be updating immediately whenever a new version is released? This seems particularly challenging in a corporate environment where frequently updating could be risky or challenging. If that's true, could you point me to any resource or documentation about this specific support pattern?

I'm not an expert on this by any means, but my impression is that R versions have a very high degree of backward compatibility, to the extent that there is an ongoing joke around R's backward compatibility with a predecessor language "S." https://twitter.com/WhyDoesR and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64903760/6851825 and https://blog.r-hub.io/2022/09/12/r-dependency/
